# difference between sizeof(array) before and after passing to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

`y` is an array of integers with 10 members (size=40 Bytes) but when I pass it to `my_function()` as `x` , `x` has 10 members but if I try to get it's size (`sizeof(x)`) I will get 8 Bytes as result.

Could you please explain why this happens ?

```
void my_function(int x[]) {
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));
}

int main() {

  int y[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(y)/sizeof(y[0]));  // Output : 10
  my_function(y);  // Output : 2

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: my_function() just gets a pointer to an integer which is 8 bytes on your system.  It has no way of knowing the size of the structure it is pointing to.

Comment: @jmq - What is that integer ? the address of array ?

Comment: `sizeof` shows the size of the *type*, not the data sent in. The type doesn’t have size of the array so it is just a pointer and there’s no size information available. You always need to give the size to the function separately

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointers when passed as function parameters, so in `my_function` the statement `printf("%d\n", sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));` is equivalent to `printf("%d\n", sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int));`. On your machine and with your compiler, the size of the pointer is equal to twice the size of an int.